# How can I convert a TS Type/Interface into an object with the keys for that type and the primitives it's made of?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection

Explanation with an example:

I have the following TS interfaces/types:

```
interface Stock {
    name: string;
    value: number;
}

type Account = {
    username: string;
    portfolio: Stock[];
}
```

I now want to have some magic function to turn the `Account` type into an object like this:

```
{
  username: {
    type: 'string',
  },
  portfolio: {
    type: 'array',
    items: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: 'string',
        },
        value: {
          type: 'number',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

This might be asking for too much since 'array' is not a JS primitive, so maybe that should be 'object' instead - but I hope this gets the idea across.

Very important to note where is that I don't nessecarily have an object that conforms to this type in runtime - I only have the interface/type - no objects to actually go through.

I believe this topic is related to `reflection`, but any ideas on how to achieve something like this would be appreciated.

The idea is to be able to do this in runtime which is where the trouble comes from. I want to generate an AST from the interfaces/types and have it recursively travel all the interfaces/types that are being used by all the libraries.

Comment: You want an actual object?  Then this isn't something TypeScript alone can give you; there is no runtime reflection of TS types.  You need code generation or to use the TypeScript Compiler API or some other build step that will read your TS code and generate other stuff from it.

Comment: @jcalz what alternatives to an object are there? I'm open to using something that's outside of TS/JS if it already exists.

Comment: A better approach is to define your types using a more strictly-defined structure (e.g. JSON Schema) that can then be used to generate a less strict structure (the actual TS types). The TS handbook [links](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#schema) to the JSON Schema for TS Config files as a reference; the source for that is [here](https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/acb78980a532436336c3f4d0b1a691d9ae7f0bc9/src/schemas/json/tsconfig.json).

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538396/how-can-i-convert-a-ts-type-interface-into-an-object-with-the-keys-for-that-type#comment136696550_77538396) A format like JSON Schema can offer additional constraints that TS cannot (e.g. specifying that the concrete value of a `number` type must be an integer within a range of min to max). Such information would be lost in the conversion to a TS type, but could be useful in validation tasks in other parts of your program and tooling.

Comment: I've used libraries like Zod and ts-io, and they do the job when I'm writing these types. The issue however is when I'm using external libraries and their types. I don't want to have to write Zod schema for every single external type that I want to use. And of course 99% of libraries don't have with Zod types built in.

Comment: So far, 'ts-json-schema-generator' seems like it gets pretty close, however it's failing to run for most libraries and their types unless it's something really simple. It doesn't seem to work with multiple files, just single files of TS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to build JSONSchema of your TypeScript interfaces.

For this, I'd use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-json-schema-generator

And then just run `npx ts-json-schema-generator --path 'your-interface-file.ts' --type 'your-name'`

Or, using programmatic code:

```js
const tsj = require("ts-json-schema-generator");

/** @type {import('ts-json-schema-generator/dist/src/Config').Config} */
const config = {
    path: "your-interface-typescript-file.ts",
    tsconfig: "path/to/tsconfig.json",
    type: "type-name",
};

const schema = tsj.createGenerator(config).createSchema(config.type); // This is the schema you look for
```